# Should a proposed edit to an accepted answer be approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just ran across a proposed edit to an answer that was already accepted. The edit was not something to fix grammar or spelling, but rather to add another option into the answer different from what the answered had already suggested. The edit was also done by an anonymous user with 1 rep.

My inclination would be to post the (short) edit as a comment and explain the situation briefly, then reject the edit. That way the answerer can judge whether or not to include the edit.

What are the thoughts on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case, based on how you've described it, I would say it should be rejected as it sounds like it should be its own answer (which even a new user can add).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion

- If you know the edit to be correct, and it adds to the answer, approve it.
- If you know the edit to be incorrect or it changes the meaning completely, reject it.
- Otherwise, leave it to someone else to decide.

In short, it depends on the particular edit and your knowledge on the topic.